# different animation-delay for each li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to set different animation-delay for each li element. Starting from 0 and increasing of 0.25s

```
const $li = [$("div.navigation li")];
let $navLoadingTime = $("div.navigation li").css("animation-duration");

$(document).ready(function () {
    // steps loading
    const $liLength = $li[0].length;
    const $delay = $navLoadingTime.replace("s", "");

    for (var i = 0; i < $li[0].length;) {
        i++
        $li[0].css("animation-delay", $delay * i + "s")
    }
})
```

So far I have created something like above.
it is almost ok. However, it increases i into the maximum and sets the same maximum delay value for all of the li elements.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: `let lis = $("div.navigation li")
for(let i in lis) {
  lis.eq(i).css('animation-delay', \`${i * 0.25}\`)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing css() on all the `<li>` in that collection, isolate the individual element objects with `eq()`

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < $li[0].length;) {            
     $li[0].eq(i).css("animation-delay", $delay * i+1 + "s");
     i++
}
```

Or using `each()`

```
$li[0].each(function(i){
   $(this).css("animation-delay", $delay * i+1 + "s");
})
```